Command run 'apt autoremove' with ModuleNotFoundError
I have an annoying error on, among others, command run sudo apt autoremove: it outputs following error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'. I checked for this package pip list | grep six, and it is there. Package 'requests_unixsocket', however, is not there even after I install it. Any help is appreciated.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.30.19) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 240, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import os, glob, subprocess, os.path, time, pwd, sys, requests_unixsocket
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_unixsocket'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debian/deb822.py", line 240, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


I tried installing both six and requests_unixsocket again in an environment, but it does not solve the issue.

sudo pip list | grep six ? sudo python3 -m pip list | grep six ?

First comment outputs the package. Second does not.

This means pip runs under a different python. Check: head -1 $(sudo which pip) — it's most probably #!/usr/bin/python3.X, not default python3. Also compare sudo python3 --version and sudo pip --version

To restore default six you need something like sudo apt reinstall -y python3-six

Worked like a charm. Free stack overflow points if you post as the answer

To restore default six package run
sudo apt reinstall -y python3-six


Mayeb you are insterested into helping me with this other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78564846/cron-job-with-database-throws-operationalerror-when-connecting-to-database . It is related to docker and SQLAlchemy

@BrunoHenriquePeixoto I use Docker but not docker-compose. Seems like a problem with internal network — no connection between containers.

Where do you think, I can seek for help?

@BrunoHenriquePeixoto https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker-compose%5D+network should be a good start. Let's me add the tag to that question…
