Cron job with database throws OperationalError when connecting to database
I have a task that needs to be periodic. I created a repository with minimal requirements, as far as I can do, using a Dockerfile, a docker-compose.yml and a Makefile. Beside, it requires database connection, which is crucial to store data I will scrap regularly. The work is here to anyone to see [1].
[1] https://github.com/brunolnetto/db-cron-docker
The reproduction instructions are:

Clone the repository;
Run pip install virtualenv && virtualenv .venv;
Run source .venv/bin/activate;
Run pip install -r requirements.txt;
Rename .env.template to .env
Run docker compose up -d;
Run make up;
Run make log-cron.

After 5 minutes, as set up in Dockerfile, it should connect to database using the engine, create a database instance with .env name. The following error appears to me instead when I use command docker logs -f cron-task
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "db-cron-task" (192.168.32.2), port 5434 failed: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

docker-compose.yaml:
version: "3.8"

services:
  db-cron-task:
    container_name: db-cron-task
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - cron_net
    expose:
      - "$POSTGRES_PORT"
    ports:
      - "$POSTGRES_PORT:$POSTGRES_PORT"
    command: postgres -c listen_addresses='*' -p $POSTGRES_PORT
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data_ 

  cron-task:
    container_name: cron-task
    depends_on:
      - db-cron-task
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - cron_net
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./alembic/versions:/app/alembic/versions:ro
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c "alembic upgrade head" 

networks:
  cron_net:

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim-bullseye

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy your application code
COPY .env .

# Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install the required packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron python3 python3-pip postgresql-client

# Create the log directory
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs

# Cron jobs
RUN echo '* * * * * python3 /app/src/main.py >> /app/logs/cron.log 2>&1' > cron-config

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab cron-config

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /app/logs/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD echo "starting" && \
    echo "continuing" && \
    (cron) && \
    echo "tailing..." && \
    : >> /app/logs/cron.log && \
    tail -f /app/logs/cron.log

The file src/main required is available on link: https://github.com/brunolnetto/db-cron-docker/blob/main/src/main.py .
This seems a very routinary operation in computer science, which makes me question life choices.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/47303141/7976758 This question seems to be about very close task — 2 containers, one with a DB…

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  "Run a Make rule in some external repository" isn't enough detail; please include the actual Docker command that's being run and any required source code directly in the question.

@DavidMaze I added Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml files as well as reference to file src/main.py. Is this enough?

Where do you configure the database connection?  The error message mentions port 5434; should this be the standard PostgreSQL port 5432?  (Connections between containers don't use or require ports:.)
